# c#/winforms: ItemCheckEventHandler after new checkstate has been applied

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, event-handling

i am looking for an event for a CheckedListBox, that fires after the checkedstate of an item has changed.

the ItemCheckEventHandler is not good for me, because it fires BEFORE the new state has been applied.

thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? To see what has been selected, or if something in particular is?

Comment: to see if something in particular is. in the event i want to launch a function that iterates over all the values and needs the new values of the items.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're looking for is the check state after the check, you can use the ItemCheck event's ItemCheckEventArgs which includes the Index, the NewValue, and the CurrentValue.

Comment: thanks. yes i tried that already, but i will need the newvalue applied in the items-array. and not just in some eventargs structure.